# Executing pwd command in csh script

Tags: csh

I'm trying to print the location in which I'm running my script from.

I tried to use the following:

```
#! /bin/csh -f
var=$(pwd)

echo $var
```

i get the following output:

> Illegal variable name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're using is for bash, ksh, zsh and a few others.

Csh has it's own syntax for assigning to variables AND doesn't support the `$( cmd ...)` form of process substitution.

Try

```
#! /bin/csh -f
set var = `pwd`   

echo "$var"
```

Note that to do the equivalent of `export var=x`, you would do

```
setenv var `pwd`
```

And as @Carpetsmoker reminds us, `[t]csh` has 2 environment variables that include this info,

```
 $cwd
 $PWD
```

so there is no reason in this case, to incur the extra process expense of using command-substitution, so your script can be

```
#! /bin/csh -f
set var = $cwd
#OR
set var = $PWD


echo "$var"
```

Finally, as good coding practice for any shell, note that I've quoted the reference to `"$var"`. You should make it a habit to quote your variables, this will eliminate a whole class of problems where using `echo` strips out any extra white space AND keeps path or filenames with spaces as one unit.

IHTH

Comment: Minor addition for completeness: There are also the `$cwd` and `$PWD` variables; you probably want to use `$cwd` (see `tcsh(1)` for details). This means you don't have to run `pwd` at all.